# como puedo evitar el error header? al imprimir txt desde php con consuta While

Tags: php

Toda la web me anda Exelente casi imprime lo que quiero solo que una linea sobra.

y es esta:

**

```
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\traductor\index.php:50) in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\traductor\index.php</b> on line <b>47</b><br />
<br />
```

**

este es el codigo fuente:

```
<?php

include_once "./includes/obdc_conex.php";
$tabla =$_POST['tabla'];
$tabla2 =$_POST['tabla2'];
$type =$_POST['type'];
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{

if($tabla<>'Dataespanol123')
    {   
        //Verificar Staff
        $certi = ("SELECT Top 1 Type
        ,TypeID
        ,ItemID
        ,ItemName
        ,ItemDesc
        ,Reqlevel
        ,Slot
        ,Country
        FROM OMG_GameWEB.dbo.$tabla
        WHERE Type BETWEEN $type
        ORDER BY RowID ASC");
        $resultd0 = odbc_exec($dbConn,$certi);
        while($row1 = odbc_fetch_array ($resultd0))
        {
                    header('Content-type: application/msword');
        header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=documento_de_texto.txt'); 
        $contenido="INSERT INTO OMG_GameWEB.dbo.$tabla2 (Type,TypeID,ItemName,ItemDesc,Reqlevel,Slot,Country) values (".$row1['Type'].",".$row1['TypeID'].",".$row1['ItemName'].",".$row1['ItemDesc'].",".$row1['Reqlevel'].",".$row1['Slot'].",".$row1['Country'].");";
        echo $contenido;
        }
    }
    ELSE
    {   
        //Verificar Staff
        $certi = ("SELECT Type
        ,TypeID
        ,ItemID
        ,ItemName
        ,ItemDesc
        ,Reqlevel
        ,Slot
        ,Country
        FROM OMG_GameWEB.dbo.$tabla
        WHERE Type BETWEEN $type
        ORDER BY Id ASC");
        $resultd0 = odbc_exec($dbConn,$certi);
        while($row1 = odbc_fetch_array ($resultd0))
        {
        header('Content-type: application/msword');
        header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=documento_de_texto.txt'); 
        $contenido="INSERT INTO OMG_GameWEB.dbo.$tabla2 (Type,TypeID,ItemName,ItemDesc,Reqlevel,Slot,Country) values (".$row1['Type'].",".$row1['TypeID'].",".$row1['ItemName'].",".$row1['ItemDesc'].",".$row1['Reqlevel'].",".$row1['Slot'].",".$row1['Country'].");";
        echo $contenido; 
        }
    }   
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Traductor by Jvc

</title>
<link rel="Shortcut Icon" href="./images/icon.jpeg" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<center>

<form action="<?php
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
?>" method="POST">
<table>
<tr><td><select name="tabla"  required/>
                        <option value="">Selecione el Typo de Tabla a Traducir</option>
<option value="Dataespanol123">Importada desde Access</option>
<option value="Original_Lenguaje">Tabla En Espa&ntilde;ol</option>
<option value="Lenguaje_sin_Especiales_Original">Tabla Que reemplaza Caracteres</option>
<option value="Lenguaje_Idioma">Tabla traducida</option>
<tr><td><select name="tabla2"  required/>
                        <option value="">Para Insertar en?</option>
                        <option value="Original_Lenguaje">Tabla En Espa&ntilde;ol</option>
                        <option value="Lenguaje_sin_Especiales_Original">Tabla Que reemplaza Caracteres</option>
                        <option value="Lenguaje_Idioma">Tabla traducida</option>

<tr><td><select name="type"  required/>
                        <option value="">ver entre Types</option>
                        <option value="1 AND 30"> 1 al 30</option>
                        <option value="31 AND 60">31 al 60</option>
                        <option value="61 AND 90">61 al 90</option>
                        <option value="91 AND 120">91 al 120</option>
                        <option value="121 AND 150">121 al 150</option>
                        <option value="151 AND 200">151 al 200</option>
                        <option value="1 AND 200">TODO</option>
</table>
<p><input type="submit" value="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Enviar&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" name="submit" /></p>
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

De hecho genera la hoja de txt pero la linea esa que tiene partes html es molesta.

puede hacerse con un select cualquiera de 2 o tres el detalle es solo quitar eliminar ese error.
Que arroja al descargar el txt.

Comment: utilize la funcion eliminar espacios en blanco y lineas vacias y sigue el error.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque te funcione veo algo raro en el código que es meter header() dentro de un while.
No sé cuantas veces se ejecutará ese while, pero cada vez que lo hace, llamas a:

```
header('Content-type: application/msword');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=documento_de_texto.txt');
```

Entiendo que deberías sacar esas líneas del while para que se ejecuten solo una vez.

Por otro lado, hay 1 aspecto básico en el uso de header() que es que debe llamarse antes de que se escriba algo por pantalla. Es decir, no puede haber un echo antes del header().

Espero que te sirva.

Saludos.

Comment: Sospeche lo del while lamentablemente no puedo eliminarlo, por que necesito corra al menos unas 20.000 veces, ¿alguna sugerencia solo quiero que descargue el contenido de la variable  "$contenido="INSERT..." en un archivo .txt

Comment: No tienes que eliminarlo, es normal que lo necesites. Lo que debes es sacar los header() de dentro del while para que se ejecuten solo una vez al principio del código.

Comment: ¿Como seria el ejemplo? pues busque de varias maneras antes de publicar como hacerlo. la verdad no comprendi

Comment: Empieza probando a poner las líneas con header antes del while, de modo que el while solo sirva para incluir el contenido que se quiere mostrar y ya previamente se hayan ejecutado las líneas con header.